# How to auto-mount a bitlocker-encrypted vhdx on a network share as soon as it is available?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker, vhd, automount

I have a VHDX file on a (samba) network share

I'd like to automatically mount that VHDX file (including entering the bitlocker key) whenever I join the network that contains that file.

How can I achieve this in Windows 10 (I don't mind storing the bitlocker key in cleartext on the computer that should mount the vhdx)?

Comment: I don't think that you can monitor if a certain server is available (except from polling it periodically). But if the server is only available in a certain network environment this post may be helpful: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/trigger-launch-program-script-connecting-to-specific-network/